# type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query

Ao tentar fazer uma consulta usando **IQueryable**, recebo o seguinte erro:

> Error 3   The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set()'

1 º - Tenho 3 entidades

classe pai que é uma interface: **não possui uma tabela na base para ela**

```
public interface IParentEquipment
{
    string DaughterOperativeNumber { get; }
}
```

e duas classes filhas que são abstratas:

```
[Table("TB_EQPT_SUB")]
public abstract class EquipmentSub : IParentEquipment
{
    [Column("OPERATIVE_NUMBER")]
    public string OperativeNumber { get; set; }

    public string DaughterOperativeNumber
    {
        get { return this.OperativeNumber ; }
    }
}

[Table("TB_EQPT")]
public abstract class Equipment : IParentEquipment
{
    [Column("OPERATIVE_NUMBER")]
    public string OperativeNumber { get; set; }

    public string DaughterOperativeNumber
    {
        get { return this.OperativeNumber ; }
    }
}
```

Eu possuo um método para buscar um **EquipmentSub** ou **Equipment** através do número operativo.

```
  public T FindGenericEquipmentByOperativeNumber<T>(string operativeNumber) where T : IParentEquipment
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _ctx.Set<T>();
        QueryFilter<T> queryFilter = new QueryFilter<T>();
        query = query.Where(s => !(s.DaughterOperativeNumber.Equals(operativeNumber)));
        query = query.Where(queryFilter.GetFilter);
        return query.Single();
    }
```

Eu percebi que se eu alterar minha interface **IParentEquipment**, para um **abstract** o erro some.

```
public abstract class IParentEquipment{

}
```

---

Por que não posso usar uma interface na minha consulta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro acontece porque a *constraint* do método `Set` pede que o tipo `T` (o tipo que o método espera) seja  um tipo for referência (`where TEntity : class`).

Colocar uma interface na *constraint* não obriga que o tipo seja por referência, por isso o erro.

Para corrigir, adicione a *constraint* `new()` ou `class`.

```
where T : class, IParentEquipment

where T : new(), IParentEquipment
```

Você pode ler sobre as restrições em: [Constraints on type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Comment: a sintaxe fica: `where T : class, IParentEquipment`, obrigado me ajudou muito =)

Answer (score 3):

Porque a assinatura do método que você está usando exige assim:

```
public virtual Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity> () where TEntity : class;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/TypeEntity.cs).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Por alguma razão que eu posso investigar ele precisa que o tipo adjacente seja uma classe, por isso ele colocou `class` como restrição, então uma interface não pode ser usada diretamente. Pode indiretamente, no tipo que vai usar aí.

Então você tem que usar uma restrição semelhante, pode usar um `class` ou um `new()`, aí exigirá um tipo concreto, ainda que ele seja caracterizado pela interface.